# How to iterate properly using page token in Calendly?

Tags: python, api, request, iteration, calendly

I want to get the information of all the pages that are generate.
This is my code:

```
import requests
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
final_response = response.json()
print(final_response)
```

I received a response like this:

```
{
  "collection": [
    {
      "uri": "https://api.calendly.com/event_types/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "count": 1,
    "next_page":"https://api.calendly.com/event_types? 
                 count=1&page_token=sNjq4TvMDfUHEl7zHRR0k0E1PCEJWvdi"
  }
```

With that page_token (https://api.calendly.com/event_types?count=1&page_token=sNjq4TvMDfUHEl7zHRR0k0E1PCEJWvdi) that is generated I want to iterate in all the pages and get all the information until "next_page"is "null"

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use `next_page` url and do new request with this URL in loop until the `next_page` URL is None. You need to provide same auth headers for each request, but you don't have to provide search params, because they are already included in `next_page` URL. [documentation](https://developer.calendly.com/api-docs/ZG9jOjE1MDE3NzI-api-conventions#keyset-based-pagination)